# XCode and Swift files for version control

Tags: swift, xcode

So I have a `.gitignore` created, which I have basic files included in there, but when it comes to a Swift and `.xcodeproj` project..

Which one of these files are the only ones that I need inside Github?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you need both .pbxproj and .xcworkspace, however, it depends:

1. `.pbxproj` file contains metadata, file references, configuration... which use to execute/build the project.
2. `.xcworkspace` contains and manages subprojects. A common scenario is using cocoapods. If you're developing a small project that's don't need to depend on any 3rd parties, you don't have to create xcworkspace.
3. `xcuserdata` folder is safe to ignore. It contains some temporary info like user state, files opened, folders opened.

Comment: Thanks @son, I only utilize Swift Package Manager and dependencies there, so no cocoapods.

Comment: Yeah, Swift Package Manager is pretty cool. It is just an example of what you can do with it, keep going.